# Energy integral of $u_{tt}+du_t-\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega \times (0,\infty)$ is uniformly bounded in t

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So here's the full equation:

1. $u_{tt}+du_t-\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega \times (0,\infty)$, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain with a smooth edge and $d > 0$
2. $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega \times (0,\infty)$
3. $u(\,., 0) = u_0$in $\Omega$, $u_0 \in H^1_0(\Omega)$
4. $u_t(\,.,0) = u_1$ in $\Omega$, $u_1 \in L^2(\Omega)$

I aim to demonstrate, through a formal calculation, that the energy integral $E(t) = \int_{\Omega} u_t^2+|\nabla u|^2\,dx$ is uniformly bounded in $t$.

My idea was to derive $E(t)$ and to see where this could bring me to, but I'm encountering difficulties with it

Could you provide me a hint, what should I do here?

Comment: One typical strategy is to differentiate the energy with respect to time and show it’s non-increasing.

Comment: \begin{align}
E' &= 2 \int_{\Omega} u_{t} u_{tt} + \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_{t} dx \\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{IBP}} 2 \int_{\Omega} u_{t} (u_{tt} - \Delta u) dx \\
&= - 2 d \int_{\Omega} u_{t}^{2} \\
&\le 0
\end{align} and hence $E(t) \le E(0) = \dots$